# How to rollback nested transactions in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have root transaction (in `PaymentProcessor#process`) has several nested transaction (in `BusinessServiceHelper#saveItem`). I expect if there's an exception in my root transaction (in `PaymentService#pay`) then this transaction will rollback and **inner transactions will rollback too**! Accordingly the result of `saveItem(item)` method is cancelled. **But that doesn't happen**.

[image]

Nested transactions are not rollbacked after the rollback of root transaction! I see changes from `saveItem(item)` method in my db after rollback of root transaction. How can I achieve rollback for nested transaction as well in this case?

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class PaymentProcessor {
  @Transactional
  public void process() {
      businessService.doSmth();
      paymentService.pay();  // throws exception
  }
}
```

.

```
public class BusinessService {

  public void doSmth() {
    for (List<Item> item : items) {
        try {
            businessServiceHelper.process(item);  // open new transaction
            notificationService.notify();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("Failed process”);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

.

```
public class BusinessServiceHelper {

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void saveItem(Item item) {
      updateItem(item);
      saveItem(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: what considerations were behind `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`?

Comment: Because each item should be processed in its own separate transaction. So if this item transaction fails it'll not affect other transactions

Comment: However I'd like to cancel this nested transaction if the **root** transaction fails

Comment: well, in SQL terms you actually need savepoints, in spring-tx savepoints are implemented via Propagation#NESTED: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NESTED. Pay attention to the statement `Actual creation of a nested transaction will only work on specific transaction managers`, hibernate, for example, does not support this feature.

Comment: It is not a nested transaction it is a total new unrelated transaction. hence that won't work. NESTED != REQUIRES_NEW and it might not even be supported by your JDBC driver, technology stack or database.

Comment: Any suggestions for this case?
Only option is switch to jdbc for this chain of methods and use JDBC DataSourceTransactionManager?

Comment: The reason behind HBN does not support savepoints is it is required to "rollback java state" when rolling back to DB savepoint, and that is the same regardless what tx manager in use. Switching to JDBC is an option but you will loose the advantage of domain model. Theoretically you may acquire JDBC connection from HBN session, call setSavepoint/rollback and use stateless HBN sessions.

Answer (score -1):

in my opinion, if all services are inside your app or module no need to open a new transaction for every service  you can access it directly   so
better to collect them in as one transaction  >>> useCase Transaction
BTW   if you divided the services as sperated transaction using  propagation(Required new ) each transaction will be commited speratly and no way to rolback it
steps  :

1. create a UseCase Service class   and add this method with name  doSmtUseCase
   mark it as  @Transactional
2. call all services needed in your use case
3. surrounded with Try ... catch   to handle business cases rollback

```
 @Service
 public class UseCase {  
private final BusinessServiceHelper  serviceHelper;
private final PaymentProcessor paymentProcessor ;

@Autowired
public UseCase(BusinessServiceHelper  serviceHelper , PaymentProcessor PaymentProcessor ){
this.serviceHelper=serviceHelper;
this.paymentProcessor =PaymentProcessor ;
}


  public void doSmth() {
        TransactionStatus transactionStatus = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();

    for (List<Item> item : items) {
        try {
           //call your services ....
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("Failed process”);
                transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly(); //  you can exclude this line and rollback will be automatic   but if you have business case   you have to rollback manualy 
        }
    }

  }
}
}
```

Comment: In general, that won't work due to plenty of reasons, for example: you are ignoring exception, what will be the db state after that?

Comment: DB state as per the transaction, 
@AndreyB.Panfilov   please tell me  plenty of reasons, this code is working and tried before  
exception  did not ignored   , i mentioned that if there any business case to handle you must handle the transaction rollback  manually  
but for any technical Db Exception, rollback will be automatic ...
and Btw I show The way (One Transaction per use case ) Not the code 
There is no way to handle Many transaction rollbacks

Comment: Imagine you are transferring money between accounts, in order to do that you need at least 2 db round trips: 1 for withdrawal and one of deposit, now, somewhere between withdrawal and deposit you got exception, ignored it and committed tx - you will get a mess in db.

Comment: target is to handle all operations with maintaining the Db state correctly described  to be UseCaseService with  One transaction
 if you make it one transaction so all operations in all rounds will be in the same transaction ( deposit, withdrawal,.....) all of these operations will be under the same transaction so in any (exception  ) the transaction will roll back directly. 
but if you use ( @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
that means: creating a separate transaction for each operation and 
you could not roll back the committed one

check Michael`s Comment